# Where has my downloaded mp3 file gone on my microsoft phone?

Tags: downloads

I have been sent an email with an mp3, which I have downloaded on my windows phone, but now I can't find it on my phone

Comment: Was this received with the built in mail app, a third party mail app, or via webmail in the browser? Additionally, what OS are you running on your phone?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned which Windows version you're using (8.1 or 10). If you're on 8.1 there's an app in the Store called [Files](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/files/9wzdncrfj3pl). It's made by Microsoft. This app gives you a detailed view on your files sortened by type (Documents, Music, Pictures etc). Download it and you'll find your file in no time.

[image]